# What is Xa = X (a= indice) in the given function y=6x-x²

Tags: calculus

I am doing a homework assignment, and I don't understand the question. In the question I am given a parabola, and the function y=6x-x² of that parabola.

Now there is a rectangle with the points A,B,C,D drawn in the middle of that parabola, Where point D and C are on the parabola (C and D are the top points of the rectangle), and point A and B are on the X axis.

In the question they ask me to calculate the surface of the rectangle and they give: Xa = x, where a is written as an indice. What do they mean by Xa = X? **What value is Xa supposed to hold?**

Can anyone hint me so I understand what they mean by Xa = X? I dont want the answer to the assignment :)

Comment: By surface of the rectangle, do you mean area? Once you've computed where the parabola touches the axis, you know the width of the rectangle. Now all you need to do is compute the height. I'm not sure what the $x_a$ denotes.

Comment: @NilayKumar yes sorry, English is not my first language. The parabola touches the x axis at x=0 and x=6, but doesn't that just say that the width of the parabola is 6? How does that give me the width of the rectangle?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. As Ragnar says below, $x_A$ is likely the $x$-value of the point $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_A=x$ probably means that the x-coördinate of the point A is $x$. Now the problem is to find the area of the rectangle expressed in $x$.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought, but what value does the x hold?

Comment: Treat it as an unknown variable. Solve for the area in terms of $x$.

Comment: @NilayKumar I dont think its possible to calculate the area if Xa is unknown

Comment: Well, $X_A$ is 'known' to be equal to $x$. (Where $x$ could be any real value.)

Comment: @Ragnar thanks, I understand now. The rectangle resizes based on the X value :)